# Linq Count Group on List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a list of objects each with a child list of string. I am trying to get a count on unique strings in the child lists.

Example objects:

```
private class ForumUser
{
    public List<string> RegisteredForums { get; set; }
}
```

Pupulating the example

```
List<ForumUser> forumUsers = new List<ForumUser>
    {
        new ForumUser {RegisteredForums = {"Forum1", "Forum2"}},
        new ForumUser {RegisteredForums = {"Forum1", "Forum2", "Forum3"}},
        new ForumUser {RegisteredForums = {"Forum1", "Forum2", "Forum3", "Forum4"}},
        new ForumUser {RegisteredForums = {"Forum1", "Forum2", "Forum3", "Forum4", "Forum5"}}
    };
```

Expected output:

Dictionary<'distinct forum name', 'count of forum'> result

```
Dictionary<string, int> result = forumUsers.GroupBy(&lt;your cleverness here&gt;
Forum1, 4
Forum2, 4
Forum3, 3
Forum4, 2
Forum5, 1
```

thank you

Comment: btw your initialization script will need to have `RegisteredForums = new List<string> {` instead of `RegisteredForums = {` otherwise you will get a null reference exception on createion....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
forumUsers.SelectMany (x=> x.RegisteredForums ).GroupBy (x => x).ToDictionary (x =>x.Key,x=>x.Count())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
forumUsers.SelectMany(f => f.RegisteredForums).GroupBy(s => s)
```